# Why my posting is taking me to wrong URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

When I'm posting, it takes me to

> example.com/shop.:community_name

instead of

> example.com/shop/:community_name

**My routes.rb**

```
resources :communities, :path => "shop", do
    resources :community_topics, :path => "topic", :as => :'topic'
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @community, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
...
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Destroy', 
    :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')),
    :class => 'btn btn-danger', :name => 'destroy' unless @community.new_record? %>
<% end %>
```

**update action in communities_controller.rb** I use to_param that's why using community_name

```
def update

        @community = Community.find_by_community_name(params[:id])      

        respond_to do |format|
            if @community.update_attributes(params[:community])
                format.html { redirect_to communities_path(@community.community_name), notice: 'Community was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { head :no_content }
            else
                format.html { render action: "edit" }
                format.json { render json: @community.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
end
```

Comment: Don't you have a typo in your routes? `:as => :'topic'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
... redirect_to community_path(@community.community_name) ...
```

in the `update` action of your `CommunitiesController`.

Answer (score 1):

hate named routes...

```
redirect_to @community
```

Comment: You will end up on the url containing the id of the community.